# PHP fopen returning TRUE

Tags: php

PHP's [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) is supposed to

> Returns a file pointer resource on success, or FALSE on error.

```
$f = fopen ($logfile, "a");

file_put_contents("/tmp/foo", gettype($f)."--".print_r ($f), TRUE);
```

The `fopen` is printing `failed to open stream: Permission denied` in the Apache log, which is what I expect in this particular case, however the error-handling logic that comes after isn't working because `if ($f)` succeeds.

The trace in `/tmp/foo` tells us

```
boolean--1
```

I guess I can use `is_resource` to make the error handling work, but this looks like a bug in PHP, no? Or is there something else that could bring about this situation?

Comment: `or FALSE on error. `. so type will be Boolean always. Php returns  are Boolean values when the context is function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a minor misuse of print_r is leaving confusion.  Note that if you wish to use print_r "inline" then a second parameter is required.

```
echo print_r($f, 1).' '.TRUE;
```

That's going to print:

```
1
```

The reason it prints a space and then 1 is that $f is FALSE, which in print_r prints nothing.  But if you ask a string to print TRUE directly, it converts it to an integer representation, or "1".

Try this:

```
if ($f) {
  echo 'f!';
} else {
  echo 'no f';
}
```

You'll find that there is "no f" if fopen fails.  Try using this test:

```
if ($f !== false) {
```

That way you'll be sure it's a resource.

Answer (score 0):

What system are you on? It works as expected here:

```
<?php
$f = fopen('/var/log/mail.err', "a");
var_dump($f);
if ($f === false) {
    echo 'Not a valid stream';
}
```

Outputs:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fopen(/var/log/mail.err): failed to open stream: Permission denied in <b>/foobar.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
bool(false)
Not a valid stream
```

Tested on Debian. PHP7.0.